# What is an 'inflated type'?

Tags: c#

In the [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeReference.html) they talk about *inflated type* such as in here:

*Field value cannot be a specific specialization of a generic type(inflated type).*

What does that mean exactly ?

Comment: I guess a *specific specialization* of e.g. the generic type `List<T>` would be a `List<string>`?

Comment: The standard term is a Constructed Generic Type https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isconstructedgenerictype?view=netframework-4.8, or a Closed Generic Type.  Which here is the same as just Generic Type, as that's the only kind of Generic Type that an object instance can have.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Mono's documentation](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/runtime/docs/generics/), which Unity's terminology may well be based upon (with Unity internally using Mono), defines it as a synonym of a type instance, i.e. a generic type with concrete types assigned to its generic type parameters:

> ### Terminology
>
> Type/Method instantiation == Type/Method instance == Inflated Type/Method.

Therefore, in the sentece you cite from Unity's documentation, it sounds like "inflated type" is meant to be a shorter way to express the entirety of "specific specialization of a generic type".

In other words, the field value must not be of a generic type with supplied type parameters.

*If I may hazard a guess, that might have something to do with the typical difficulty that you always stumble over when trying to write a serialization/deserialization for arbitrary .NET objects - as long as you work with non-generic types, all is fine and `GetType().FullName` will give you the full class name, which can be resolved again upon deserialization. However, once you come across a generic type, `GetType().FullName` will only return the number of type arguments, so both `List<string>` and `List<int>` will become `` "System.Collections.Generic.List`1" ``, from where you will get back to the original types only with some extra work.*

Comment: Very nice answer -- warning to the reader:  I have no specific knowledge about this, so I am *just assuming* everything above is correct.

Comment: You lost me. Do you have examples of inflated vs non-inflated types?

Comment: @JeromeJ: `List<string>` and `List<int>` are two inflated types. Both are based on the non-inflated type `List<T>` (or just `List<>` in C# syntax).

Comment: I work at Unity and can confirm that this is the correct understanding of what that documentation means, and also a good summary of the technical reason behind the lack of support.    Note: to work around this limitation you would declare a class that derives from the generic, with the type parameters supplied in that declaration.

e.g. 
[SerializeReference] Node<string> WontWork; // Not supported

[Serializable] class NodeOfStrings : Node<string> {}
[SerializeReference] NodeOfStrings MyNode; // OK

Note: List<> has built in support, so "[SerializeReference] List<MyNode>..." is ok.